# How to recover a override Shelveset in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

By Mistake I have Override my Shelveset in TFS. Is there anyways to recover my old files. I don't have TFS Admin Access.

Thanks for your reply in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunate short answer: no.

An admin could, be restoring the whole TFS server from a previous backup containing the old shelveset to a temporary machine.